# Sonar 6.1 : Unable to TFS annotate the project and Missing blame information for the following files

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, annotate, blame

We are using Sonar 6.1. SCM provider for this project is: tfvc. Even though we have provided the tfvc settings like username and PAT/password we are getting the below error.

2017-01-18T06:44:22.9837227Z INFO: SCM provider for this project is: tfvc

2017-01-18T06:44:22.9837227Z INFO: 1245 files to be analyzed

2017-01-18T06:44:25.0818549Z ##[error]ERROR: Unable to TFS annotate the project which raised the following authentication exception: TF30063: You are not authorized to access extranet URL.

2017-01-18T06:44:25.0818549Z INFO: 0/1245 files analyzed

2017-01-18T06:44:25.0818549Z ##[error]WARN: Missing blame information for the following files:

2017-01-18T06:44:25.0818549Z ##[error]WARN:   * C:/../../../../*.cs

2017-01-18T06:44:25.0818549Z ##[error]WARN:   * C:/../../../../*.js

Comment: Can you share the build definition?

Answer (score 1):

> You are not authorized to access extranet URL.

It appears that the analysis process can't get to TFS to pull the required blame data.

Comment: How can we overcome with this kind of issue.Build is running on Azure VM and able to access the same project with extranet url